# Deploying a Spring Boot Application on AWS Using AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to deploy a Spring Boot Application on AWS Using AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but I don't see the option to upload a jar file, only zip and war (?!)

and in this tutorial they are deploying a jar file:
https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/devops/deploying-a-spring-boot-application-on-aws-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

[image]

Comment: You can just upload the JAR file using the same uploader for the ZIP or WAR file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Tutorial: How to deploy a Spring Boot application to Amazon AWS using Elastic Beanstalk

**Youtube video tutorial:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYVlzoRMa3U

**Source Code Link:** https://github.com/marcthomas2013/spring-boot-aws

**Full tutorial link:** https://mtdevuk.com/2015/02/10/how-to-deploy-a-spring-boot-application-to-amazon-aws-using-elastic-beanstalk/

### Creating a Spring Boot War:

1. Start up eclipse IDE with the Spring Extensions installed. For Luna add this link to your update installer http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.4/
2. You’ll also need Tomcat server installed in Eclipse. If you don’t have this setup then search Google for setup instructions before you continue.
3. Select File->New->Other->Spring->Spring Starter Project
4. Set the name and the artifact to spring-boot-aws
5. Change the packaging from jar to war (This does a couple of things that I’ll explain later)
6. Select Actuator and Remote Shell so that we have some RESTful services to test the app with.
7. Click Finish

It has created a simple Spring Boot application with some REST services like /beans that will return a JSON object of all the beans in your application.

### Deploy your application using Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

1. Login to Amazon AWS.
2. In the main control panel select Elastic Beanstalk under Deployment & Management.
3. Click on Create Application in the top right corner.
4. Enter the Application Name and click Next.
5. Environment Tier – Web Server
6. Predefined Configuration – Tomcat
7. Environment Type – Single instance
8. Click Next
9. Select Upload your own, click Browse and locate the war you created earlier.
10. When the application is uploaded you will see the next page where you select your URL.
11. Enter a name and click check availability to see if you can use it.
12. Click Next
13. We don’t need a RDB in this example so click next here.
14. In this next step you are defining the EC2 instance that will be created, if you are using a free trial then stick to the free t1.micro instance type.
15. EC2 Key Pair, can be left unselected. You won’t need it for now and most likely you won’t have one configured yet. This will be covered in a later post.
16. Click Next.
17. In Environment Tags click next again because we don’t care about this.
18. Review the configuration, and then click Launch.

Amazon AWS will now provision your server, install the Tomcat server and deploy the war file that you uploaded. It does take a good 5-10 minutes for this action to complete.

**Another Full tutorial is available here:** [Step-by-Step Guide to Deploying a Full-Stack Spring Boot Application in AWS](http://carlmartensen.com/step-by-step-guide-to-building-and-deploying-a-database-backed-spring-boot-web-application-in-aws)

If you want to deploy code in the official way using CLI, then you can go through [this tutorial](https://exampledriven.wordpress.com/2017/01/09/spring-boot-aws-elastic-beanstalk-example/):

**P.S** If you had problem of **502** Bad GateWay nginx you have three options
i prefer changing the spring boot port to 5000
check here for more details [Bad GatWay problem 3 options to solve it](https://dzone.com/articles/run-your-spring-boot-application-on-aws-using-elas)

Comment: the source code was useful, but youtube video unavailable

Comment: @BaDrAmer I have linked up to another youtube video. Please check

Comment: The link to ***Step-by-Step guide*** is no longer available :(