# 404 not found on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a spring boot project that runs normally on localhost. But when I upload the WAR on AWS using ElasticBeansTalk, I have a 404 not found.

The access to DynamoDB works fine from the CLI.

The variables on the properties file are the same as the one I am using to access DynamoDB from the CLI

properties file:

```
amazon.dynamodb.endpoint=http://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
amazon.aws.accesskey=***
amazon.aws.secretkey=***
```

CLI:

```
aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [********************]:
AWS Secret Access Key [********************]:
Default region name [us-west-2]:
Default output format [json]:
```

I don't know why I am having the 404 not found on AWS

Answer (score 0):

AWS is set to listen to port 5000 by default, so you just need to set `server.port=5000` in your `application.properties` file before creating your WAR. Or you can set an `SERVER_PORT` environment property to change it from 5000 to 8080 that Spring uses.

Another issue I ran into was creating the environment using Java, when you should actually be using Tomcat.

Great step by step [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43720045/deploying-a-spring-boot-application-on-aws-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk) and extra context [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40695374/502-bad-request-on-aws-spring-boot-application).